# Django - Print each model/form out separately

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I use {{form}} to print out the whole form. I wonder is there any way to print each element separately? I tried {{survey.location}} or {{survey.get_location_display}} but it doesn't work. Below are may models.py, forms.py, views.py and home.html.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Survey(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Survey
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ["location", "education"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SurveyForm

def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = SurveyForm()
    return render(request, "home.html", {"form": form})
```

home.html

```
<form method='POST' action= "" >{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>    
</form>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Thank you. It does what I want know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, here's one way from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template):

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.subject.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
        {{ form.subject }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.message.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
        {{ form.message }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.sender.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
        {{ form.sender }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
        <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
        {{ form.cc_myself }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @mdislam. You're very supportive :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`{{form.field_name}}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) to print each field of the form separately.

From Django docs on [rendering fields manually:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

> Each field is available as an attribute of the form using `{{
>   form.name_of_field }}`, and in a Django template, will be rendered
>   appropriately.

```
{{form.location}} # renders 'location' field of a form

{{form.education}} # renders 'education' field of a form
```

`{{form.location}}` in the template will render something like:

```
<input type="text" name="location" maxlength="120" ../>
```